# MCC for Sales cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales

We are going live with MCC in a few Days.

During Installing the Package we need to Perform this step

'After login, select who to install the package for.'

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_install_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5

what are the permissions that will be assigned to the profiles we selected?

Is it only 'System Admin' that we need to select or 'profile of tracking User[who is the bridge for both MCC and Salesforce cloud]

In Prod we have around 10 profiles.

If users with some 'n' profile need to see Email sends and send Analytics and that profile is not included in above step. Can we fulfill this requirement?

[I know we can add classes and vf pages that comes with Package can be added at profile level, but will this be enough].

Please Help we on this one.

Thank you,
Meghana.

Answer (score 0):

You should just install the package for admin only. The features of connector are available to everyone for who you select Marketing Cloud Connect User permission set - admin permissions are not needed.

> This person accesses Marketing Cloud Connect functionality in the Sales or Service Cloud, Marketing Cloud, or both. Access to Marketing Cloud Connect functionality in the Sales or Service Cloud is managed through CRM permissions and page layouts. Access to Marketing Cloud Connect functionality in the Marketing Cloud is managed through Marketing Cloud Connect permissions. A license for both Marketing Cloud and Sales or Service Cloud is required at a minimum.

You can see the [full list of user types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_user_types_and_permissions.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), provided in the context of MCC.